# Change font size in Emacs cli

Tags: configuration, emacs, fonts, command

How can i change Emac's default font size in command-line, not the X version of emacs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're running Emacs inside a terminal session isn't the font size determined by the terminal windows rather than by Emacs?

Comment: hmm, i'm not sure. Seems probable.

Comment: yep, just had to change terminal font size. Thanks.

Comment: I'm quite sure that's the case.

Comment: @Mark F - feel free to accept the answer then. :-)